# Angular, how to send an array of ids with an http delete and receive it on ASP.NET Core delete backend end point?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I have a service in which I would like to be able to send an array of Ids with a single http.delete. So far I have the following:

```
`
removeLeaguePictures(leaguePics: LeaguePicture[]) {
    const options = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }),
      body: {
        idss: JSON.stringify(leaguePics.map(lp => lp.id))
      }
    };
    return combineLatest([
      this.leaguePictures$,
      this.http.delete<boolean>(this.galleryUrl, options)
    ]).pipe(...)
`
```

this however does not seem to be sending the list or I just do not know how to retrieve it on the back end Asp.Net core endpoint

In my backend server I have the following action :

```
`
[HttpDelete]
    public async Task<ActionResult<bool>> Delete([FromBody] long[] ids)
    {...}
`
```

But I cannot get the ids array to be populated. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it a little bit different:

```
const options = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  }),
  body: JSON.stringify(leaguePics.map(lp => lp.id))
}
```